# Assign IP address for one computer within each VLAN

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vlan

I have been asked if there is a solution to expose a single machine (Linux Server with honeypot installed) to multiple VLANs, I mean, a single machine will have many IP addresses belonging to each VLAN. The goal is to host a honeypot to every VLAN which exists in the network.

I have a Linux box with a gigabit Ethernet card (let's say `eth0`), and I thought maybe using virtual interfaces configured like this:

> eth0:1 -> IP 10.10.0.15 / GW 10.10.0.1
>
> eth0:2 -> IP 10.10.1.15 / GW 10.10.1.1
>
> eth0:2 -> IP 10.10.5.15 / GW 10.10.5.1

and so on. So each VLAN might be accessible within each one of the virtual interfaces.

Is this even possible to achieve with the default Debian 9?

Answer (score 3):

First, it is important to remember that without a bunch of weird(complex) routing, you can only have a single default gateway.

Ignoring the routing/gateway issue a /etc/network/interfaces file on a Debian might look like this assigning IPs from multiple VLANs.

```
# native vlan
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.10.0.15
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.0.1

# tagged vlans

# iface eth0.VLAID inet static
#        address 10.10.VLAID.15
#        netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth0.10 inet static
        address 10.10.10.15
        netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth0.20 inet static
        address 10.10.20.15
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Great answer by Zoredache as ever but be aware that it you're using a very recent RHEL-variant that a lot of the network setup has changed, if you are then just use the online documentation or come back to us ok.

Comment: @Chopper3 they did mention using Debian 9 in their question.  Which will support the older both the older style of config `ifupdown` which my example is for.  Debian 9 also supports the systemd method of network configuration out of the box, but I didn't have tested VLAN example handy for that.

Comment: Zoredache is correct... I would only add (if it's not clear enough) that there is no need to configure virtual network interfaces like eth0:1, eth0:2, etc., you can use directly tagged VLANs instead (eth0.10, eth0.200, etc.); manually you can create VLAN by ie. `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.10 type vlan id 10` and add IP address with  `ip addr add 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 dev eth0.10` and after bring it up with `ip link set dev eth0.10 up` (this is iproute2 method)

Comment: Sorry yes, completely missed that!

Comment: @Zoredache where in this configuration would you put the dns server settings? Under each vlan?

Comment: DNS settings are global to the computer. Linux doesn't use different resolver per-interface. So I usually but my dns resolvers on the loopback interface, that is assuming I am using resolvconf that pulls the dns settings from the interfaces config on a given system.